# How to inset a number joined with a string into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, string, insert, numbers

How to insert this `917678904@tmomail.com` into mysql database? .

I tried putting single quotes around it and without the single quotes but both methods fail.

```
// This is my query:

$n = 917678904@tmomail.com;
$table = "invites";

if(!mysql_query("INSERT into $dbname.$table (accepted_by, accepted_on, phone, email,  reffer) 
              VALUES('NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', `$n`, 'NULL'")){
                 echo mysql_error();
}
```

This is the table structure

```
accepted_by VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
accepted_on VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL
phone VARCHAR (11) NULL
email VARCHAR (250) NULL
refferer CHAR (3) NOT NULL)
```

This is the error message with SINGLE quotes around $n:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

I am using MYSQL version 5.0

Comment: Please provide queries that you have tired.

Comment: show what have you tried , so we can see

Comment: Actually single quote should work... Whats your table structure & query?

Comment: Please show your schema, query and error.

Comment: Looks like you're inserting NULL into NOT NULL...

Answer (score 1):

```
`$n`
```

in your values field is incorrect. Backticks are used to escape field names, which the value of `$n` almost certainly isn't. It should be using regular quotes:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., '$n', ...)
                        ^--^--
```

As well, `'NULL'` is also incorrect. That will try to insert the literal characters `N`, `U`, `L`, `L` into your db table. For an actual SQL null value, remove the quotes:

```
... VALUES(NULL, NULL,....)
           ^^^^
```

And lastly, you say your table structure has `refferer`, but your query string is using `reffer`. Maybe just a typo, but worth pointing out.

Comment: SO should have a 30 second delay timer for you so I can get an answer in ;). +1

Comment: The joys of 101wpm typing speed?

Comment: Sigh, I had to do an online speed test and my average was 95 :(

Comment: Also, `accepted_by`, `accepted_on` and `referrer` are `NOT NULL`

Comment: @Marc B:  Even after fixing my errors, which you point out I am still getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@tmomail.com, NULL' at line 2.  That's with double quotes around $n.

Comment: @TrevorPrime You're not closing the field properly. The e-mail should be enclosed in single quotes. I would recommend you separate your query and echo it like: `$query = "INSERT INTO ... ";` then `echo $query;` and finally `if(!mysql_query($query)) ... `